# How to run a function in a single line if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this if statement i am trying to convert into a single line to be used in a terminal shell, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Essentially the code sort of looks like this:

```
import module

if condition:
    module.runCustomMethod()
else:
    pass
```

so i tried to write this like so:

```
import module;module.runCustomeMethod() if condition == True else pass
```

but no matter how i arrange it, it always gives me a syntax error. how would i go about running a method in this way?

Comment: Where does `condition` come from?

Comment: You probably shouldn't actually do this, but… `if condition: __import__('module').runCustomMethod()` allows you to get rid of the `import` statement, so you get around the problem of having two statements, But again, you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: For future reference (I fixed this one for you), almost all questions tagged python-2.7 should also be tagged python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is pretty ugly, and there are better ways to do it, but…

```
import module;module.runCustomeMethod() if condition == True else pass
```

The problem here is that `pass` is a statement, and Python expressions can never contain statements.

Since you're not using the value of the expression, you can replace that `pass` with any expression that's harmless to evaluate:

```
import module;module.runCustomeMethod() if condition == True else None
```

Now there's no `SyntaxError` in your code. Although it's still not going to work, because that `condition` isn't defined anywhere, so it's just going to raise a `NameError` instead. But if that isn't a problem in your real code, this will work.

As a side note, you almost always just want `if condition`, not `if condition == True`. Only use that if you specifically only want to accept `True` and reject other truthy values like `1`.

---

If you're doing this in a sh script, the cleanest solution is probably this:

```
python <<EOF
import module
if condition:
    module.runCustomeMethod()
EOF
```

Comment: hi thank you so much for your feedback. yes it definitely is an ugly way of writing it, but it is an attempt to keep things contained in one file. although now that i think if it it could be done differently. but i wanted to explore options. and of course in this example i habent defined the condition, but this was more of a skeleton of what i was trying to achieve. i do not have a means of testing this right now so let me post an update in about 16 hours...

Comment: and yes it seems to have worked once i changed "pass" to "None". thank you so much!